# TinyMCE - customization "insert/modify table" popup

Tags: tinymce

I use TinyMCE in my application. Is there any possibility to remove fields from popup, which is shown after button "Insert Table" is clicked? I would like to have only "columns" and "rows" fields.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box, but you could "customize" the template for this popup.
You can find it in `/tiny_mce/plugins/table/table.htm`